# Hadoop : start-dfs.sh and start-mapred.sh script not running

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, configuration

I have installed Hadoop [by following this tutorial.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144433/how-to-install-hadoop/279623#279623)

I installed it using ppa.

When I reached **step 12** : Starting Hadoop Cluster.

I got stuck.

When I do `cd ~/tasdik/hadoop/bin/` **It says no such file or directory**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that directory actually there?

Comment: no. I am not able to figure out where was hadoop installed.

Comment: If you successfully did step 11, you can do step 12. It's the same directory.